# Do attributes in functional dependencies need to be atomic?

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

Let's say I have a Relation `R := {id, name, emails}`
Obviously `id -> name` is a functional dependency but is `id -> emails` also a Functional Dependency?

From what I understand `id ->> email` would be a multivalued dependency if you would turn the Relation into `R := {id, name, email}`.

But does this only apply after normalization and would it be functionally dependent before?

Comment: Functional dependences and in general all the normalization theory is defined in the relational data model. If an attribute is not atomic then its “container” is a generic table, not a “relation” as intended in the normalization theory, and for this reason the concepts and definitions of the theory cannot be applied to it.

Comment: @Renzo Normalization theory can be devided into 2 orthogoanal notions, 1NF & higher NFs. Other than possibly requiring a 1NF, higher NFs don't care about the types of attributes, which can be anything, including relations. A relation by definition has 1 value per attribute per tuple. There is no problem having a FD determining a relation-valued attribute.

Comment: What is your 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question? [ask] Where & how are you 1st stuck finding, quoting & applying definitions of "relation", "FD", "MVD, "normalization" & "atomic"? (From an authoritative source, eg a (good) textbook.) What do you mean, "atomic FD"? "Normalized" has 2 senses, "... to 1NF" & "... to higher NFs".--What do you mean by it? Why is id -> name "obviously" a FD? Why isn't id -> emails? PS By definition a relation has 1 value per attribute per tuple. ["1NF" has many meanings. "Atomic" means nothing in particular.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097)